# Microsoft Edge Back Button and CSS target selector

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Here is some sample code:

```css
:target {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#test">test</a>
<div id="test"> this is a test</div>
```

When you click on the anchor, the div it targets turns blue. On Firefox, Chrome and Opera the style resets itself when you press the back button. However, with Edge, the url updates, however the style does not reset. The style only updates when you resize the browser window. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Ha ha, hope the 6 people using edge don't visit you site. But really, a javascript `if` function that is browser specific and resets it on back.

Comment: This appears to be a known issue https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8271689/ I've bumped it.

Answer (score 0):

This bug in Edge, when styles not updates when :target changed, but updates when window resizing, occurs when parent with id contains link to this id, like this:

```
<a href='#modal'>open modal window</a>
<div id='#modal'>
    ...
    <a name='#modal'></a>
    ...
</div>
```

If you remove inner "< a name='#modal'>< /a>" or move it to outside, then the bug disappears.